# Compare DATE without year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to display the list of employees who were hired in the first quarter of each year.

In my table, I have an attribute called `emp_hiredate`. 
Currently, I only know how to get the employees who are hired on the first quarter of 2020,2019 and the values I set every time. Is there a way I can do something that is LIKE date?

For example date the dates (ddmmyyyy)  '20-Mar-2018','10-Jan-2019','26-Jan-2020' is an example of the expected output.

And '15-Apr-2017','22-Dec-2019' are examples of dates I do not want.

```
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE  emp_hiredate <= '31-Mar-2017'
```

This is so far what I know. All I need is to make it check each year. It would be something like this

```
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE  emp_hiredate < '31-Mar'
```

I know this is incorrect but if it should help you understand what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`DATEPART()`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_datepart.asp) to get the quarter of the year.

```
DATEPART(quarter, emp_hiredate ) = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for informing me about DATEPART() i did more research and have come up with SELECT * FROM employee WHERE  DATEPART(month,emp_hiredate) <= DATEPART(month,'01-Mar-2000'). I used the next question had something similar but not quarter. edit: accident enter

Comment: @MichaelSWS `WHERE MONTH(emp_hiredate)<=3` can also work

Comment: @Nenad Zivkovic Yeah, That makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Select * form Emp_table
where datediff(months,hi